# Can I filter TT_NEWS in Typo3 by a date range?

Tags: date, range, typo3, tt-news

I'm building a Typo3 website with the TT_NEWS extension; now I want to create a TT_NEWS list/latest view with a certain date range, but I cant find a way to do so.

I can't use the ARCHIVE function because I need a specific data range.

I hope that one of you knows the magic answer :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try setting an exact date range for the archive with TypoScript:

```
plugin.tt_news.amenuStart = 1.2.2003
plugin.tt_news.amenuEnd = 4.5.2006
```

This is assuming you only need one date range. For more than one range, maybe news categories would do the trick, but you'd need to assign them manually.

Answer (score 2):

For tx_news use this in TypoScript:

```
1.settings.timeRestriction = 01.02.2003
1.settings.timeRestrictionHigh = 04.05.2006
```